# Java One Array data to another Array

Tags: java, arrays

Basically I need for example to  array1 in position 0..9 to contain items form another array from posinion 20..29. How do i do this? I tried playing with for loop but this way i can only get data from the same positions in both arrays.

Comment: Can you please post your for loop? Thanks.

Comment: You need to give more detail about what you are trying to do and post the code you are trying to use to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// copy indices 20-29 from array2 to indices 0-9 in array1
System.arraycopy(array2, 20, array1, 0, 10);
```

Comment: oh, i think I need to read documentation more often, didn't even knew about this method.